# I shouldn't be review audited on my own posts

Tags: bug, review

Was given a [post to review I made myself](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/80729) about 2 weeks ago.

Was "only a test" but I wonder if that's not something that should be filtered out...

> [image]

Comment: Sounds like the programmers missed an edge case :)

Comment: Did you pass the audit?  :-)

Comment: @DanPichelman yes, I did.

Comment: @DanPichelman it would be epically hilarious to recommend deletion and fail the audit in this case :)

Comment: @gnat yes, but I somehow felt unqualified and nearly pressed skip, but thought it must be someone's joke :)